# Java IO issue when using SVN versioning system

Tags: java, svn

I have a Java program that is supplied a directory name, gets a list of all the file in that directory using `dirName.listFiles()` and then iterates through every file parsing information from them.

The files would normally all just be normal text files, but I am using SVN and there seems to be a directory called `.svn` in my `dirName` directory which is causing my program to fail because `.svn` is a directory and not a text file.

Now, I could implement filters using a `FileFilter` object, but I would really only expect text files to be in that directory in the final program.

My question is: Is there a way round my issue without using a FileFilter? I also think that my program is ignoring the `.svn` directory in other programs that I've written, so I'm not sure why it's an issue now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  You want to be able to filter the directory listing, but without using a `FileFilter`?

Comment: @Oli - I feel as though the way SVN works shouldn't be interfering with my program in this way. But basically I realise that I should just use a FileFilter. If the `.svn` directory is doing this then my program obviously isn't at all robust. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have this issue with many version control systems (not just SVN) as some of them have files on disk that help identify where the working copy comes from (.svn for SVN, view.dat for clearcase).  You really should just implement a FileFilter to exclude those, or use the ones from commons-io:

[makeSvnAware](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.3.2/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/FileFilterUtils.html#makeSVNAware%28org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29)

It's null safe, so if you give it null input, it simply returns an svn filter for you.  If you give it another IOFileFilter (a subinterface of FileFilter) it simply returns one that does an AND between the existing filter and the svn filter.

```
FileFilter svnFilter = FileFilterUtils.makeSvnAware(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call `isDirectory()` on each object that `listFiles()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible soulutions (at least):

1. `FileFilter` or `FileNameFilter`
2. `isFile()`

Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

Better than using java for file and directory search, i would prefer writing a jni program and use C's dirent.h and stat.h to differentiate between files. The jni program would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

If `dirName` is not the root directory of your working copy, you can upgrade to the latest version of svn. This doesn't have an .svn directory for every directory but only for the root.